# Research on Verbs that Require/Prohibit Reflexive Pronoun

Tags: verbs, reflexives

In Huddleston & Pullum (2002, p. 1483-1499), there are a significant number of rules on how to use the reflexive pronoun in English, especially the verb domain reflexive, which mandates, allows, or prohibits an object that is in reflexive form.  This source did not actually explain about verbs that allow (ie you can use either reflexive or non-reflexive pronouns) and verbs that disallow objects in reflexive form (they say in this source "inadmissible").

There are some grammar books that give some verbs that fit one of the requirements (eg Quirk et al [1985, p. 356-361] and Swan [2016, Section 14, item 178]), but I need to check the literature concerning those verbs that **don't** permit reflexive form of object. So, I want to ask:

1. Where can I find some research about verbs that accept or reject reflexive form objects?
2. Research on preferences between reflexive, non-reflexive, or inadmissible reflexive on certain types on verbs in a some syntactical structures.

I want to limit this research only for basic reflexive form, not the empathic nor override one.

From what I found in these literatures, I mainly conclude few things here:

1. From Quirk et al. (1985, p. 358) these are verbs that characterized as "reflexive verbs", such as: *absent oneself (from)*, *avail oneself (of)*, *demean oneself*, *ingratiate oneself (with)*, *perjure oneself*. This is enhanced by the proof that Huddleston & Pullum (2002, p. 1488) lists those verb and addition of another verb, listed here: *apply (to)*, *behave*, *busy*, *compose*, *conduct*, *enjoy*, and *exert*.
2. Quirk et al. (1985, p. 358) lists verbs that is called "semi-reflexive", which allow the verb to be not accompanied with reflexive pronoun, such as (bracket means optional): *behave (oneself to), hide (oneself), prepare (oneself) for, wash (oneself), dress (oneself), identify (oneself) (to be), prove (oneself) (to be), worry (oneself)*
3. Same source from above, it lists verbs that is called "nonreflexive", which rejects reflexive verb but may require non-reflexive counterpart, such as: *blame, accuse, admire, amuse, dislike, feed, get, hurt, persuade*
4. Huddleston & Pullum (2002 p. 1486) prefer to categorize usage of reflexive pronoun mainly by its syntactical structure. The main division of basic reflexive is the domain (single or dual-head domain), and then this single-head domain is splitted into verb domain and noun domain.
5. Continuing from Point no. 4, The syntactical categorization in verb domain is listed as following:

a) Reflexive pronoun in direct object function (clarifies verbs that has mandatory reflexives, explaining structures that has optional reflexive [mainly object near prepositional phrase], explaining inadmissible reflexive [mainly complement of preposition that required to be anaphorically linked to subject, close to mandatory usage, but this time the non-reflexive part is required])

b) As indirect object (mandatory, except in some dialects), *I bought myself a new car*, for example.

c) As predicative complement (mandatory, relatively rare for it to be anaphorically linked to the subject, mainly idiomatic), Example: *You should just try to be yourself*

d) As an object of preposition (can be mandatory, allow, or prohibits the reflexive in certain conditions). In mandatory setting, PPs functioning as complement of the prepositional verb (*He thinks of himself as overworked*) or it can be "the type that the mandatory reflexive has antecedent to be object of the verb or preposition (as in *Tim praises Mary to herself but criticize her to everyone else*). In optional reflexive setting.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Please give the reference for the Stirling & Huddleston for the benefit of other readers here :)

Comment: Or some examples of the kind of verbs you are talking about.

Comment: Please wait for me to give you summary of what I got, for it become readable and easier to deliver and answered. I will edit the question as soon as possible when the summary is ready

Comment: Hello, M.R. With some verbs, reflexives are available for certain meanings (John hurt her / him (Tim, say) / himself / *herself). Obviously, some transitive verbs won't accept reflexive pronouns (John descended himself) or will do so only in certain situations (*John took himself / John took himself too seriously / John took himself off the roster ...). But these are limitations on the verb + object construction in general. // Quirk et al discuss what they term 'nonreflexive verbs' in 6.25c (but I'd say this is a misnomer: their examples are unconvincing).